# .NET TPL Start a task after one ends indefinitely

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I have an application which process images extracted from database. I need to process various images in parallel, and because of that i'm using .NET TPL with Tasks.

My application is a Winforms app in C#. I just have the option to choose how many processes will start and a Start button. The way that i'm doing right now is this:

```
private Action getBusinessAction(int numProcess) {
    return () =>
    {
        try {
            while (true) {
                (new BusinessClass()).doSomeProcess(numProcess);
                tokenCancelacion.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled process");
        }
    };
}

...

for (int cnt = 0; cnt < NUM_OF_MAX_PROCESS; cnt++) {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(getBusinessAction(cnt + 1), tokenCancelacion);
}
```

In this case, if i choose 8 as the number of processes, it starts 8 tasks which are running until application is closed. But i think that a better approach will be to start a number of tasks which calls `doSomeProcess` method, and then finish. But when a task finishes, i would like to start the same task or start a new instance of the task that does the same, in order to having always that number of processes running in parallel. Is there a way in TPL to achieve this?

Comment: How does the Task finishes? You have a infinite loop there.

Comment: Maybe some of the overloaded Task.WaitAny method if useful for you https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd270672(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i've modified a little bit, instead having while(true) i have a static bool property in a static class, also i have the: tokenCancelacion.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); to stop execution. When i press a button to stop execution of tasks, that boolean variable changes and because of that the while loops goes out.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good fit for [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s `ActionBlock`. You create a single block at the start. Set how many items it should process concurrently (i.e. 8) and post the items into it:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Image>(
    image => ProcessImage(image), 
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8});

foreach (var image in GetImages())
{
    block.Post(image);
}
```

This will take care of creating up to 8 tasks when needed and when they aren't anymore the number would go down.

When you are done you should signal the block for completion and wait for it to complete:

```
block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

Comment: It sounds nice. The only thing that i need is, when rhose 8 tasks finishes, i need to start automatically another eight, without user intervention. Or if only one of those tasks ends, start a new one doing the same action. Thepurpose is to have always X processes active, processing images. Right now that's the reason why i use an endless loop inside my tasks, but i would like to have 8 process that ends and start new ones rather than have the same 8 process with endless loops inside them

Comment: @OscarCalderon That's exactly what `ActionBlock` does. You can of course try and implement that yourself but I would suggest using that instead.

Comment: Ok, i'll gonna try that and let you know, thank you.

Comment: There's only one thing: In your code, there's a method named GetImages which returns an image or something like that, and passes it as a parameter for ProcessImage method. In my case, i don't wanna return anything and my method doesn't receive any parameters more than thread number, which is only for presentation purposes. In my code, the method itself get his own image. How can be adapted to TPL Dataflow?

Comment: @OscarCalderon It's just an example. The point is pumping the items to be processed into the `ActionBlock`. Since your isn't already based on TPL Dataflow you need to change it to fit it.